# How to convert a JSON with arrays in tsv with jq keeping the array structure?

Tags: json, csv, jq

I need to get the content of a mysql table that has some fields that store data as a JSON array, and ingest it in another database table. I need to use a REST API for that, and it returns the records in JSON. For performance reason, I need that output to be tab tab return. Therefore I use jq's @tsv.

This works greats till it encounters a field that has a JSON array inside, jq then complains "array is not valid in a csv row".

Here's a JSON sample

```
{
"records": [
 {
        "id": 1,
        "metadata": {
            "description": null,
            "width": 0,
            "height": 0,
            "secondaryColor": "#fff",
            "callToAction": [
                {
                    "link": "/truc.html",
                    "value": "nice",
                    "colors": {
                        "primary": "transparent;",
                        "secondary": "transparent;"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "parent": null
    }
        ]
}
```

I'd like the following result

```
1  null  0  0  #fff  [ { "link": "/truc.html", "value": "nice", "colors": { "primary": "transparent;", "secondary": "transparent;" } } ]  null
```

so basically I want the array to be intact but just returned in a single row

So I wrote this

```
jq -c --raw-output '.records[]|[.id,.metadata.description,.metadata.width,.metadata.height,.metadata.secondaryColor,.metadata.callToAction,.parent]|@tsv
```

But I have the "array  is not valid in a csv row" error

Is that possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to JSON-encode the call-to-action first.

```
% jq -c --raw-output '.records[] |
[.id, .metadata.description, 
      .metadata.width,
      .metadata.height,
      .metadata.secondaryColor,
      (.metadata.callToAction|@json),  # convert this field to JSON first
      .parent
] | @tsv' tmp.json
1       0   0   #fff    [{"link":"/truc.html","value":"nice","colors":{"primary":"transparent;","secondary":"transparent;"}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the stated goal includes "null" in the output, you might like to consider mapping all the selected values using `tojson`, e.g. using `map(tojson)`.  With the sample JSON, this would produce:

```
1   null    0   0   "#fff"  [{"link":"/truc.html","value":"nice","colors":{"primary":"transparent;","secondary":"transparent;"}}]   null
```

Notice, though, that the string `#fff` is quoted.  If you don't want strings to be quoted in this way, then you might wish to consider:

```
map(if type == "string" then . else tojson end)
```

Comment: sorry, the null was an error from me as I wrote the example